# align the figure and the text in itemization LaTex

Tags: latex

I am trying to use "itemize" function in latex to illustrate some icons, icons on the left and explanations on the right, two problems 1)left figure not align up with the right text, text always lower than the figure. 2)the whole items block is too close to the left edge, add left space for the whole itemize block?

```
\begin{itemize}

    \item[{\includegraphics[width=7em]{ui_t_1.jpg}}] \textbf{Home}\\ Select to go to the Main Menu screen.\\
    \item[{\includegraphics[width=7em]{ui_t_2.jpg}}] \textbf{History}\\ Select to check the running history.\\
    \item[{\includegraphics[width=7em]{ui_t_3.jpg}}] \textbf{System}\\ Select to set up the system parameters.\\
    \item[{\includegraphics[width=7em]{ui_t_4.jpg}}] \textbf{Log Off}\\ Select to log off or shut down the system.\\
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: please make a [mre]

Comment: You'll probably be looking for the `adjustbox` package.

Comment: Off-topic: please don't abuse `\\\` for line breaks

Answer (score 0):

[`adjustbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)'s `export` option allows you access to `valign` within `\includegraphics`, where you can specify the `v`ertical `align`ment of the image you're including with respect to surrounding document elements. You're most likely after `valign=c`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item[{\includegraphics[width=2em,valign=B]{example-image-a}}] \textbf{Home}
  
  Select to go to the Main Menu screen.
  
  \item[{\includegraphics[width=2em,valign=c]{example-image-b}}] \textbf{History}
  
  Select to check the running history.
  
  \item[{\includegraphics[width=2em,valign=t]{example-image-c}}] \textbf{System}
  
  Select to set up the system parameters.
  
  \item[{\includegraphics[width=2em,valign=c]{example-image}}]  \textbf{Log Off}
  
  Select to log off or shut down the system.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```